# ZendFramework 2 integrate with Shopware

Tags: php, zend-framework2, shopware

I would like to build a zend framework2 base web application and i need to use the e-commerce engine which is from Shopware. I need to use the shopping cart and checkout feature provided by Shopware in my web app. My question will be:

1. How can I implement the checkout feature provided by shopware(eCommerce engine) into my zf2 web application?
2. How does the file structure (tree) of my zf2 should look like?

Update: Currently my zf2 structure are like
[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I downloaded the shopware package and manage to bring up something like the demo page they provided. http://en.shopwaredemo.de/

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I already have an existing website, how can I implement the 'checkout' feature provided by shopware(eCommerce engine) into my existing web application?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the DI-Container of shopware with the following code sample:

```
<?php
$shopwarePath = '/some/path/where/shopware/is';

// initialize shopware autloader
require $shopwarePath . '/autoload.php';

// create and boot kernel / prepare di container
$shopwareKernel = new \Shopware\Kernel('production', false);
$shopwareKernel->boot();

// get a service from the di container
$acl = $shopwareKernel->getContainer()->get('acl');

/** @var \Shopware_Components_Acl $acl */
$acl->isAllowed('local_admins', 'order', 'create'); // returns true
```

To start an actual dispatch you have to pass a request into the kernels handle method (https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/master/shopware.php#L109):

```
$request = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();

$shopwareKernel->handle($request)
               ->send();
```

You may also transform your existing ZF2 Request object into a shopware compatible request object and pass this into the internal dispatcher. 
We do something similar with the Symfony Request: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/master/engine/Shopware/Kernel.php#L145

Comment: I am working on the code sample you provided and I get an error saying 'resource not found on acl'. did i missed something?

Comment: Is the shopware installation your $shopwarePath points to already configured and installed?

Comment: i already installed it through project.dev/install. I am running my app on vagrant, i posted my sample tree structure of my project in my question above. I am able to open the frontend of shopware when i point my public path into Shopware/shopware.php. The home page shown up without items, but i am not able to navigate to the shopping cart or any other route. It always display the error "the url project.dev/checkout/cart not found on the server".